# How to add super class methods in Latest Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-edittext

How to add super class methods in Android Studio 1.0.1 with overridden methods automatically while creating new class.

Answer (score 2):

> Ctrl+o

```
Shortcut to add super class methods in android studio
```

Answer (score 1):

For overriding super class methods in android studio press **Alt + Insert** then you will get one Popup select **Override Methods** option in that list and then select the methods which you want Override.